# Sending log from springboot application to cloudwatch in fargate instance

Tags: spring-boot, log4j2, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-fargate

We need to configure appender to cloudwatch in our log4j2.xml.
We are using ECS cluster with Fargate instance.
Use case is we need to  categories logs in different log groups from same application based on business log type. There is way to send logs to different files using multiple loggers but how we can do same for cloud watch.
There are some libraries written for this but do we have some AWS cloudwatch log appender which we can use in our log4j2.xml. Please help

Answer (score 1):

We use Spring Boot logging default and send output to the console. This should also work for non-Spring Boot. Then using CloudFormation configure logs in the `TaskDefinition` and `LogGroup`s. You can do similar in the console with the `TaskDefinition` and create the CloudWatch logs separately.

```
Resources:
  .
  :
  TaskDefinition:
    .
    :
    Properties:
      .
      :
      ContainerDefinitions:
       - Name:
         Image:
         .
         :
         LogConfiguration:
           LogDriver: awslogs
           Options:
             awslogs-region: !Ref 'AWS::Region'
             awslogs-group: !Ref LogGroup
             awslogs-stream-prefix: ecs

  LogGroup:
    Type: 'AWS::Logs::LogGroup'
    Properties:
      LogGroupName: !Sub ${ServiceName}
  AccessLogGroup:
    Type: AWS::Logs::LogGroup
    Properties:
      LogGroupName: !Sub ${ServiceName}-api-access-logs
      RetentionInDays: 7
```

Comment: Thank you! Quite a useful answer, how about spring-boot app logger configuration, does there needed something specific?

Comment: @MindaugasK. The only change we make is to `logging.pattern.console` to have consistent message formatting across all our services. This enabled better readability of our logs in ElasticStack/Kibana.